# Why do the new materials don't show up on an imported STL file?

Tags: rendering, materials, 3d-view, import, stl

I have imported some files from Solidwork in a STL. format. When I import them in blender, they show up in the solid mode viewport, but are glitchy in material and render preview. When I try to add a new materiel, the preview is all black. I tried exporting it in a obj. format and importing it in a new blender file but it still does the same thing.[image]

Comment: Can you share a small stl that exhibits this issue?

Comment: This looks like a hardware problem. Make sure your drivers are up to date and your GPU/CPU can handle this data